# Cognos 8.3 and Oracle11g

Tags: cognos

When i place ojdbc5.jar in the c8\webapps\p2pd\WEB-INF\lib directory... i receive the error below.  And yes the content store is on an oracle 11g RAC database. I am running Oracle11g Client. Cognos version is 8.3 SP4.

[Content Manager database connection]
1. [ ERROR ] The database connection failed.
2. [ ERROR ] Content Manager failed to start because it could not load driver "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

the short of it is... and no i dont know why... but you just HAVE to use the ojdbc14.jar file.  Even though cognos documentation uses ojdbc5.jar for oracle11g.

wish i had a better answer to help future people.